# How to trim a space at the start and end of textbox?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to trim any spaces at the start of the text box and trim any spaces at the end of the textbox. So I have found this code on a website which is suppose to remove spaces at the start, end and multiple spaces in between:

```
function trim(s) {
    s = s.replace(/(^\s*)|(\s*$)/gi,"");
    s = s.replace(/[ ]{2,}/gi," ");
    s = s.replace(/\n /,"\n");
    return s;
}
```

My problem is though that first of all which one of the 3 lines of code is the one where it trims spaces in the middle because I don't need that one. But the main question is how do I get the textbox to access this function?

I tried using onkeypress but this hasn't worked, below is what I have tried:

```
<p>Search: <input type="text" name="questioncontent" onkeypress="return trim(s)" /></p>
```

So what I want is that for example if this phrase is entered in textbox ' My Name is Pete '. Then it should remove the spaces at the start and end so it reads 'My Name is Pete'. But how do I get this to work?

UPDATE:

Found out that trim() is jQuery, so does anyone a javascript equivalent for this which can be hand coded to remove spaces at start and end of textbox?

Comment: $.trim() is an option if you want to use JQuery

Comment: Oh, right, oops, so really my question is does anyone know the javascript equivalent?

Comment: If you check every keypress, what about when the user types multiple words separated by spaces?  Are multiple words allowed?  If the user types "foo bar" at what point should trailing spaces be eliminated?  If it's per character; when "foo " is entered, the space will be removed, making "foo bar" only inputable via paste.

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand Like I said I want the spaces to only be removed if there is one before the first word has been entered and after the last word that has been entered. No spaces in between words should be trimmed

Comment: Is the function .trim() not woking. I mean take the value in the end( when the user focuses out of the input box) and replace it by  .trim() version http://w3schools.invisionzone.com/index.php?showtopic=11773 this might help

Comment: The function I am using isn't working, but I dont know whether the reason that is how I am accessing it thru onkeypress? because the trim code above was what I found from a website and people commented stating that it worked

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to change your HTML :

```
<p>Search: <input type="text" name="questioncontent" onchange="return trim(this)" /></p>​
```

Pass the input element as a parameter to trim and use onchange instead of onkeypress.

Then trim needs to be :

```
function trim (el) {
    el.value = el.value.
       replace (/(^\s*)|(\s*$)/gi, ""). // removes leading and trailing spaces
       replace (/[ ]{2,}/gi," ").       // replaces multiple spaces with one space 
       replace (/\n +/,"\n");           // Removes spaces after newlines
    return;
}​
```

This modifies the value of the input element, removing leading and trailing spaces, replacing multiple spaces with a single space, and removing any spaces after newline characters.

JSfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/jstoolsmith/ZNQQm

Comment: How do you use this in angular 1.x.x, I have defined trim inside my controller, when I reference in html it says trim is not defined.

Comment: add a dot on entering two space quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the comments.. it really depends on how the function is used.  I attempted to test with it on `onkeypress`, however that didn't have your desired effect.  I did however get something [similar](http://jsfiddle.net/Daedalus/TNTxL/1/) to what you desired, though I'm still unsure if that's what you wanted.

I had to modify the function slightly to work with your code, but basically, on blur, it executes the function, and alters the input text accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
function trim (el) {
    el.value = el.value.
       replace (/(^\s*)|(\s*$)/, ""). // removes leading and trailing spaces
       replace (/[ ]{2,}/gi," ").       // replaces multiple spaces with one space 
       replace (/\n +/,"\n");           // Removes spaces after newlines
    return;
}​
```

Comment: this is the write ans

Comment: can you explain whats going on?