# save the string using ltrim and rtrim

Tags: xpages

I am trying to save the string that there is no space from the left end and no space from right end.

From these two websites, [website1](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_8.5.3/com.ibm.designer.domino.api.doc/r_wpdr_standard_string_ltrim_r.html) and [website2](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_8.5.3/com.ibm.designer.domino.api.doc/r_wpdr_standard_string_rtrim_r.html). I start to use ltrim and rtrim to remove space.

In the xpage, there is a edit box which using data binding to bind to a form called Topic, the field name is topic. There is also a button and a computed field.

Here is the full code of the xpage.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
<xp:this.data>
    <xp:dominoDocument var="document1" formName="Topic"
        computeWithForm="onsave">
    </xp:dominoDocument>
</xp:this.data>

<xp:inputText id="inputText1" value="#{document1.topic}"></xp:inputText>
<xp:br></xp:br>
<xp:br></xp:br>
<xp:button value="Label" id="button1">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
        refreshMode="complete">
        <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:var input = getComponent("inputText1").getValue();
var trimleft = input.ltrim();
var trimright = trimleft.rtrim();
getComponent("computedField1").setValue(trimright);
document1.save();
}]]></xp:this.action>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>
<xp:br></xp:br>
<xp:br></xp:br>
<xp:text escape="true" id="computedField1"></xp:text>
</xp:view>
```

When I run it, I can see there is no sapce from the left end of the input and no space from the right end of the input in the computed field. For example, if I type "   this is testing   ", the computed field can show the result like this "this is testing".

However in Lotus Notes Client, I open the view and I notice the saved input has the space (same as the original input) .

Then I try to put the customConverter in the edit box. The code is like this

```
<xp:inputText id="inputText1" value="#{document1.topic}">
    <xp:this.converter>
        <xp:customConverter getAsString="#{javascript:value}">
            <xp:this.getAsObject><![CDATA[#{javascript:var trimvalueleft = value.ltrim();
var trimvalueright = trimvalueleft.rtrim();
var value = trimvalueright;
value}]]></xp:this.getAsObject>
        </xp:customConverter>
    </xp:this.converter>
</xp:inputText>
```

I run it again using the same input "   this is testing   ", and I see the saved input still have the space.

After that, I open the form, in the field, I put @Trim(topic) in Input Translation and run again, the result is the same.

I don't know why the saved value still has the space even I use rtrim and ltrim. Grateful if someone let me know my mistake please. Thank you.

Comment: I intend to use `rtrim` and `ltrim` because I would like to prevent the user press the space bar accidentally before the user input the value and after input the value. I read this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10747119/how-to-trim-a-space-at-the-start-and-end-of-textbox), I don't have idea how to apply in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would lean toward the converter and forget about the convoluted save action. Also you can re-reference the value on the page again without setting it manually. Try the following:

```
<xp:this.data>
    <xp:dominoDocument var="document1" formName="Topic"
        computeWithForm="onsave" />
</xp:this.data>

<xp:inputText id="inputTopic" value="#{document1.topic}">
    <xp:this.converter>
        <xp:customConverter getAsString="#{javascript:value}"
            getAsObject="#{javascript:value.ltrim().rtrim()}" />
    </xp:this.converter>
</xp:inputText>

<xp:br />
<xp:br />

<xp:button id="buttonSave" value="Save">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
        refreshMode="complete" action="#{javascript:document1.save()}" />
</xp:button>

<xp:br />
<xp:br />

<xp:text id="computedField1" escape="true" value="#{document1.topic}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the cause is that you're updating the component value (`getComponent.setVaue()`), but saving the datasource. That would only work if the `save()` pulled all values again from all components. I'd be surprised if that was the case and could have a big performance hit.

Update the datasource instead (e.g. `document1.replaceItemValue("myField",myValue)`). Only access the component when you can't access the datasource it's bound to (e.g. in a converter / validator, because the datasource hasn't yet been updated).

Alternatively, because you're already doing computeWithForm onsave, use @Trim() in the Form.